# My Sign flag value is showing wrong? Am I wrong about how sign flag works?

Tags: assembly, flags, emu8086

I am adding `ax` and `bx`. So if MSB of the result is 1 then the sign flag=1 or else sign flag=0. Am I right? If I'm right why sign flag=0 is showing in output? Shouldn't it be SF=1? If I am wrong please correct me. I am confused

```
mov ax,20h
mov bx,80h
add ax,bx
```

Answer (score 2):

> So if MSB of the result is 1 then the sign flag=1 or else sign flag=0. Am i right?

You're right about the sign flag reflecting the most significant bit of the result, **but** in your addition `add ax, bx`you're adding 2 words and that's what makes all the difference.

Consider **adding bytes**:

```
mov     al, 20h
mov     bl, 80h
add     al, bl     ; -> AL = 20h + 80h = A0h
```

The result in `AL` has the most significant bit (bit 7) *set* and so the SF=1

Consider **adding words**:

```
mov     ax, 0020h
mov     bx, 0080h
add     ax, bx     ; -> AX = 0020h + 0080h = 00A0h
```

The result in `AX` has the most significant bit (bit 15) *cleared* and so the SF=0

### Tip

It might help to write hexadecimal numbers with as much digits as the register involved can hold.
Write `mov ax, 0020h` instead of `mov ax, 20h`.